# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.parse.ParseImageView.setParseFile(com.parse.ParseFile)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, android-parsequeryadapter

I *KNOW* what a NullPointerException is, alright?
But, what are the possible mistakes for this line of code:

```
mealImage.setParseFile(campaign.getImage());
```

to give me a`NullPointerException`?

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.parse.ParseImageView.setParseFile(com.parse.ParseFile)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.mainAdapter.getItemView(mainAdapter.java:41)
                                                                                 at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.mainAdapter.getItemView(mainAdapter.java:19)
                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.getView(ParseQueryAdapter.java:606)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

Line 41: is the first line of code I gave you. Line 19 is:

```
public class mainAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Campaign> {
```

So, what can be null? My ParseImageView is correct, correct class and column name.
How am I getting the image:
Campaign.class:

```
@ParseClassName("Campaign")

public class Campaign extends ParseObject {
    public Campaign() {
        // default Constructor
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return getString("Title");
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return getString("Description");
    }

    public ParseUser getAuthor() {
        return getParseUser("Owner");
    }

    public ParseFile getImage(){
        return getParseFile("Picture");
    }



}
```

Need more info?
**Note:** Don't go `-1`ing at me, I know what a `NullPointerException` is. So, heads up!
**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <com.parse.ParseImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#454343"
            />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**getItemView()**:

```
   @Override
public View getItemView(Campaign campaign, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_single,null);
    }

    super.getItemView(campaign, v, parent);

    ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile photoFile = campaign.getImage();
    if (photoFile != null) {
        mealImage.setParseFile(campaign.getImage());
        mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                // nothing to do
            }
        });
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(campaign.getTitle());
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.description);
    descriptionTextView.setText(campaign.getDescription());
    return v;

}
```

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate, I know what a nullPointerException is. But I don't get what is null. I used to use `mParseQueryAdapter.setImageKey("Picture")` and it worked

Comment: mealImage is null...

Comment: @IrinaAvram I know that, but why? I am getting the image from the database.

Comment: well how should I know that? you only posted Campaign. There's nothing about mealImage here

Comment: what exactly is mealImage and how do you initialize it?

Comment: I am going to assume it's a ParseImageView, and if you want me to guess there is something wrong with the id

Comment: It is a parseImageView. How about reading the logcat?

Comment: The id is perfect. Want proof? I'll edit the post

Comment: Now you are awfully nice, I did read it, that is what I based my assumtion on, but it would have been far more impressive if you would have managed to paste the declaration and initialization of mealImage

Comment: nah, I'm still not convinced... Maybe pasting the java code located in your activity before *mealImage.setParseFile(campaign.getImage());* might actually help

Comment: it might just be something as simple as writing *Picture* with uppercase

Comment: @IrinaAvram everything is correct. I'll update my post and add the getItemView() method

Comment: change this `v.findViewById(R.id.icon);` to this `v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);` or the opposite change (in your xml) this  `android:id="@android:id/icon"` to `android:id="@+id/icon"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to `findViewById` if the referenced view is not found it returns null.

You are getting `android:id/icon` and creating a new `@+id/icon` mixed up.

This is your code:

```
 ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

 <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        />
```

change

`v.findViewById(R.id.icon);`

to this

`v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);`

or the opposite (in your xml)
change

`android:id="@android:id/icon"`

to

`android:id="@+id/icon"`

---

Under the hood Android will change these id's to numbers lets say:

android:id/icon = 123
and 
+id/icon = 456

therefore

```
<View
  android:id="android:id/icon"
  ... />
```

and

```
<View
  android:id="android:id/icon"
  ... />
```

will resolve to two different numbers
(meaning looking up one when you want the other will give you a `NullPointerException`)

Comment: Thanks, THIS is what I call an answer. Wish I could +1